# How could there be a truly "pure" state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, universe, quantum-entanglement

If the Universe did start from a single point, then wouldn't all particles be fundamentally entangled? How then could there be a truly "pure" state?

Comment: Your question can be rephrased to: _"How can there be truly isolated systems?"_ So the answer is the same :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure states are a convenient abstraction for studying tiny, specially-prepared quantum systems. States of complicated systems are never pure.

One makes (very small) systems pure by careful preparation. For example, a simple spin by means of a Stern-Gerlach magnet and a screen where only the up particles can pass. More complex systems need more complex preparation to make them (at least approximately) pure.

Note also that pure states can be entangled; indeed, entanglement is usually defined only for pure states. Thus there is no conflict between entanglement and pureness.